# IE11 triggers input event when value contains umlaut

Tags: jquery, events, input, internet-explorer-11, eventtrigger

I have a strange problem,

We are loading the content to a page through ajax, response contains some input tags with values

```
<input type="text" value = "cédille" id="textField">
```

and added inputevent to the input components. Event should trigger on paste,cut.

```
$("#textField").on('input',function(){...});
```

Expecting any change in text field have to trigger the input event listener. But event triggering on loading the page when input value contains umlaut(like ä,é).

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Subbu__S/qs7oz0g0/5/

Only occurs in IE11, 
Checked in the version : 11.0.49, 11.0.50 (might be in other version)

I'm very thankful provide any solution.

Comment: @Pete if a character encoding is used that supports é, then there is no need for any additional “encoding” or HTML entities.

Comment: Can’t confirm the behavior in IE version 11.786.somethingorother, update version 11.0.49 on Win 10 - change handler in your fiddle only triggers when I manually change the field value.

Comment: change handler in your fiddle only triggers when I manually change the field value,  what it means? only triggers when I manually change the field, is there any possibility? More over event should trigger on paste, cut also.

Comment: Means, I can not confirm that this fires as soon as the page loads, resp. the input field is created - not happening for me, only when I change the field content by typing into it and then leave the field, I get an alert.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://github.com/gilamran/JQuery-Plugin-AnyChange

Comment: @CBRoe : https://jsfiddle.net/Subbu__S/qs7oz0g0/5/ try this link.

Comment: @Sandor : input event is enough to fire event on cut/paste, But using the Umlaut as value then i got the problem. Please check the js fiddle once.

Comment: Yeah, for the input event I can confirm what you described.

Comment: @SubbuS I am having the same issue? How did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with JQuery autocomplete and didn't found any `correct` way of doing this as it's browser bug.

```
$("#test").autocomplete({
    //some code
    select: function( event ) {
        onSelectDoSomething();
        return false;
    }
});
```

So `onSelectDoSomething()` was called if per-loaded input `#test` had values with umlauts

I added additional JavaScript value `var test_click = false` and also event on `#test` click.

So it look something like this

```
var test_click = false;

$( "#test" ).click(function() {
    test_click = true;
});

$("#test").autocomplete({
    //some code
    select: function( event ) {
        if(test_click) {
            onSelectDoSomething();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This is not solution I would recommend, but it's only solution I can think of without decrease compatibility of IE, or switching browser.